# HtmlUnit: how to get password field when getInputByName/Value are not possible?

Tags: forms, htmlunit

I am writing a small program to download my blog articles, some of which are protected by username and password. That's where HtmlUnit comes into play. For all the public articles, I have no problem. But for the protected articles, I need to log in using HtmlUnit. Now the host page does not provide name or value attributes in the HtmlForm. The following is a snippet of HTML code of the host page.

```
<form id="notLogin" tabindex="6" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="return false" style="outline: none;">
                        <div class="login-form-top"><input autocomplete="off" tabindex="7" id="loginName" type="text" name="loginName" value="" class="login-mod-input" placeholder="微博/博客/邮箱/手机号"><input id="loginPass" tabindex="8" type="password" name="" value="" class="login-mod-input" placeholder="请输入密码"></div>
                    </form>
```

As you can see, for the loginPass there is no name or value for me to even locate the password field. I have written the following relevant part.

```
        final HtmlForm loginForm = (HtmlForm) page.getFirstByXPath("//form[@id='notLogin']");
    System.out.println(loginForm);

    final HtmlTextInput usrnHtmlTextInput = loginForm.getInputByName("loginName");
    usrnHtmlTextInput.setValueAttribute(username);
    System.out.println(usrnHtmlTextInput);

    final HtmlPasswordInput pwdInput = loginForm.getInputByName("password");
    pwdInput.setValueAttribute(password);
    System.out.println(pwdInput);

    final HtmlPage page2 =  (HtmlPage) loginForm.getInputByValue("登录").click();
    System.out.println(page2);
```

Could you please point out for me how I can locate the password input field in this case?

Thanks in advance! Xi.

Answer (score 0):

Both inputs have an ID. An ID uniquely identifies an element in the DOM. It's the easiest and fastest way to get an element:

```
HtmlInput loginInput = page.getHtmlElementById("loginName");
HtmlInput passwordInput = page.getHtmlElementById("loginPass");
```

Relevant [api doc](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html#getHtmlElementById%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

Agree with JB Nizet, there are IDs given for both nodes, you can also use any selector, CSS or XPATH also usefull,

```
    HtmlInput login_name = (HtmlInput) page.getByXPath("//*[@id='loginName']").get(0);
    HtmlInput login_pass = (HtmlInput) page.getByXPath("//*[@id='loginPass']").get(0);
```